# Gyro for Turtlebot?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, gyro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of creating my own TurtleBot since I have most of the parts already. However it seems the sparkfun gyro suggested on turtlebot.com has been discontinued. Can anyone suggest a good alternate gyro or IMU? Preferably the device would be a drop in replacement for the gyro (i.e. will work with the TurtleBot dashboard w/o modification).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31341/gyro-for-turtlebot?/) by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [post (gyro-for-turtlebot)](http://answers.ros.org/question/12745/gyro-for-turtlebot) seems to answer your problem

---

Originally posted by [0pc0](https://answers.ros.org/users/1936/0pc0/) with karma: 78 on 2012-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you are aware you could buy the gyro built in with this power board http://store.iheartengineering.com/TurtleBot-Kit-Power-Sensor-Board/dp/B005CDNI9U?ie=UTF8&id=TurtleBot%20Kit%20Power%20Sensor%20Board&field_product_site_launch_date_utc=-1y&field_availability=-1&field_browse=3001597011&searchSize=12&searchNodeID=3001597011&searchPage=1&refinementHistory=brandtextbin%2Csubjectbin%2Cprice%2Csize_name&searchRank=salesrank from I heart engineering.

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2012-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on 2012-04-07**:
I had not seen that before. Thanks.